# Ubuntu 12.04 is the only operating system that boots my Macbook Pro 2011

Tags: 12.04, boot, unity, grub2, macbook

I have something that I am trying to figure out and would like your assistance. I have a Macbook Pro Late 2011. Great Machine but it has a notorious graphics card issue. Got the machine reflowed and it helped some boot the only operating system that it will boot consistently is Ubuntu 12.04. I've tried the latest Ubuntu. I've tried Installing 12.04 and then upgrading to 14.04 and it just doesn't work. I guess maybe the Grub installer for 12.04 allows me to select the option to boot into recovery mode , which I'm guessing probably uses the Intel Chip instead of the ATI Graphics chip, which is fine. I have Virtual box on my computer and can use that the run Debian or the latest Ubuntu. However, you guys are ending Support for 12.04 in April 2017, and this concerns me because I cannot seem to install any other version of Ubuntu on my Mac besides 12.04, is there something I can do, to bring my 12.04 operating system up to date. Or do you have any other suggestions? Thank You